# how to login a Custom User Model in django rest API framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I defined a Custom User Model in models.py whose name is Student. This model inherits Django User. I can sign up student correctly, but when I want to login , I get error.

I want to login with identity no and student no which exists in database when a student signs up.

```
models.py:
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = ((1, 'student'),
                     (2, 'professor'),)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user_type=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, 
    null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    identity_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)



class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entry_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
student_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

> ```
> serilizers.py:
> ```

```
  class CustomUserForLogin(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model = CustomUser
    fields = (
        'identity_no',
    )

  class StudentLoginView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       user = CustomUserForLogin()

       class Meta:
          model = Student
          fields = [
            "user",
            "student_no", ]

def validate(self, data):  # validated_data
    identity_no = data.get('identity_no')
    print("identity_no", identity_no)
    student_no = data.get("student_no")
    print("student_no", student_no)
    # to search username or email is a user Model
    user = Student.objects.filter(
        Q(identity_no=identity_no) |
        Q(student_no=student_no)
    ).distinct()
    print("user", user)
    if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
        user_obj = user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError("This username or student_no is not existed")
    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(student_no):  # Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct.
            raise ValidationError("Incorrect Credential please try again")
    return user_obj
```

> views.py:

```
class StudentloginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = StudentLoginView

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = StudentLoginView(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

FieldError at /system/student-login/

Cannot resolve keyword 'identity_no' into field. Choices are: courserelationstudent, entry_year, id, student_no, user, user_id

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/system/student-login/
Django Version:     1.11.17
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:

Cannot resolve keyword 'identity_no' into field. Choices are: courserelationstudent, entry_year, id, student_no, user, user_id

Exception Location:     C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path, line 1352
Python Executable:  C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['C:\Users\LELA\Desktop\APINewSystem',
 'C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
 'C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
 'C:\Users\LELA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 6 Jul 2019 05:37:50 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closer at the student filtering:

```
user = Student.objects.filter(
    Q(identity_no=identity_no) |
    Q(student_no=student_no)
).distinct()
```

And then at your models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    identity_no = ...


class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    user = ...
    student_no = ...
```

The fields `identity_no` and `student_no` are in two separate models - `User` and `Student`. Thus in your students filtering you should perform filtration on the related user model:

```
user = Student.objects.filter(
    Q(user__identity_no=identity_no) |  # <<<
    Q(student_no=student_no)
).distinct()
```

Comment: tanks to reply me. I have error in this part>>> identity_no = data.get('identity_no'). cause of using Student model, it says that Student model has not identity_no as its field

Comment: @laya what about `user_data = data.pop('user', None)` and then `identity_no = user_data.get('identity_no')`

Comment: 'Student' object has no attribute 'check_password', this is new error